# Regex to get a certain substring from a web scrape?

Tags: php, regex

I am scraping a site and getting this:

```
<input type="BUTTON" value="Geographic Footprint" name="GEO_FOOTPRINT" onclick="return OpenModalDialog('https://mspfast.elavon.com/Symphony/client/client.do?uid=0XrHleUX5MudUYVwwsGDYCl&novaid=5418812&readonly=Y&context=BOARDING&defaultRoute=GeographicFootprint')">
```

What I want is to just grab the uid: `0XrHleUX5MudUYVwwsGDYCl`

I am quite new to regex and don't really understand how it works.

I've tried doing:

```
'/value="Geographic Footprint" name="GEO_FOOTPRINT" onclick="return OpenModalDialog(\'https://mspfast.elavon.com/Symphony/client/client.do?uid=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\&/'
```

as the regex but it does not work. I get the error of `unknown modifier '/'`

Comment: "I am quite new to regex and don't really understand how it works" and yet you are trying to use it instead of using a HTMl parser?

Comment: @PeeHaa if someone is not familiar with regex, do you think they would know when to use it or an HTML parser (which they no doubt are not familiar with either)?

Comment: You forgot to escape the `/` in the url... you should probably learn more about regexes before you try to parse html **AND** javascript with them simultaneously.

Comment: It's hard enough to parse tag/attr-val but then to parse the url at the same time might be rough. Are you sure you want to use a regex ?

Comment: Here not RegEx, but fun $uid = explode('=', explode('&', explode('?', $str)[1])[0]);

Comment: What makes this node unique? Which attribute, value? I could help with a DOM example.

Comment: @stribizhev this is the only input with the name geo_footprint

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: Once you select a delimiter (`/` in this case) you can't use that character in your regex unless you escape it. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with a named group:

```
$str = "<input type=\"BUTTON\" value=\"Geographic Footprint\" name=\"GEO_FOOTPRINT\" onclick=\"return OpenModalDialog('https://mspfast.elavon.com/Symphony/client/client.do?uid=0XrHleUX5MudUYVwwsGDYCl&novaid=5418812&readonly=Y&context=BOARDING&defaultRoute=GeographicFootprint')\">";
$regex = '/uid=(?P<uid>[^&]+)/';
// search for uid literally, afterwards match everything except an ampersand 
// and capture it in a group called "uid"

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
$uid = $matches["uid"][0];
// uid: 0XrHleUX5MudUYVwwsGDYCl
```

While this might work for this particular example, it's almost allways better to use a parser (e.g. SimpleXML) for these tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to access the only element with `name` attribute having `GEO_FOOTPRINT` value:

```
$html = '<body><input type="BUTTON" value="Geographic Footprint" name="GEO_FOOTPRINT" onclick="return OpenModalDialog(\'https://mspfast.elavon.com/Symphony/client/client.do?uid=0XrHleUX5MudUYVwwsGDYCl&novaid=5418812&readonly=Y&context=BOARDING&defaultRoute=GeographicFootprint\')"></body>';
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$link = $xpath->query('//input[@name="GEO_FOOTPRINT"]')->item(0);
$val = $link->getAttribute('onclick');
```

Now, once we have the text of the `onclick` attribute value, we can consider several ways of getting the `uid` value. Here is a regex one:

```
preg_match('~[?&]uid=([^&\s]+)~', $val, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

The regex `[?&]uid=([^&\s]+)` matches `?` or `&`, then `uid` sequence, then `=`, and then matches and captures into Group 1 one or more characters other than `&` or whitespace (`\s`) (so that we do not cross another query param).

There can be other regexps (you may add `OpenModalDialog\(\'http\S*?` at the beginning of the pattern to restrict it), or try string split / substr functions, etc.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/HbGgKb)